# Splitting data frame in R

Tags: r, split

I'm new to R. I have a dataset with names in the first row, the category the names belong to in the second row, and then price observations for two year from the third row onwards. I want to split the data frame using the categories in the second row. How do I do this?

This is what my dataset looks like (on R):

[image]

This is what I want it look like (on Excel) :
[image]

Note: I cannot do this on Excel and then import because there are way too many categories.

Comment: I do not think so, I did read that post before asking this question. The problem is the structure of the dataset. I have added a capture of what my dataset looks like.

Comment: Post a capture of what ur expecting too. Not able to understand your end requirement.

Comment: Posted the end requirement capture.

Comment: @phil_t, your question is just not in the right format. Can you please check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple possiblities

```
df <- data.frame(data = c(1:12), category = rep(letters[1:3], 4))
```

1. `subset` function.

   ```
   df_a <- subset(df, category == "a")
   ```
2. basic data.frame subset

   ```
   df_a <- df[df$category == "a",]
   ```
3. into a list

   ```
   ls <- list
   for(category in unique(df$category)){
      ls[[category]] <- df[df$category == "a", ]
   }
   ```

Comment: I am not able to use subset or your other suggestions because the category does not have a row name. I have added a capture of what my dataset looks like as of now. I am not sure I can add a row name for the second row.

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer in your question. The split or split.data.frame functions would do it. The second argument must be of factor type for this to work.

Example

```
newdf <- split.data.frame(iris, iris$Species)
newdf
```

Comment: I am not able to use split because the category does not have a row name. I have added a capture of what my dataset looks like as of now. I am not sure I can add a row name for the second row.